# How to add go binary as bitbucket pipeline artifact?

Tags: go, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

Hello I am trying to add the output binary of my pipeline to the build-in artifactory.

```
image: golang:1.13

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - PACKAGE_PATH="${GOPATH}/src/bitbucket.org/${BITBUCKET_REPO_FULL_NAME}"
          - mkdir -pv "${PACKAGE_PATH}"
          - tar -cO --exclude-vcs --exclude=bitbucket-pipelines.yml . | tar -xv -C "${PACKAGE_PATH}"
          - cd "${PACKAGE_PATH}"
          - go get -v
          - env GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 go build
          - go build -v
          - ls
        artifacts:
          - fx_update.exe
```

However, the binary does not end up in the artifactory:

[image]

So I threw this `ls` command in there to see if the .exe is present and Indeed it is:

[image]

Does anyone know why it's not doing what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you `cd` to the package directory before creating artifacts. Artifacts definitions are relative to the build directory, not to the current working directory (see this page for more details https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/using-artifacts-in-steps-935389074.html). You can fix this by copying the `fx_update.exe` to the base build directory:

```
- step:
    script:
      - PACKAGE_PATH="${GOPATH}/src/bitbucket.org/${BITBUCKET_REPO_FULL_NAME}"
      - mkdir -pv "${PACKAGE_PATH}"
      - tar -cO --exclude-vcs --exclude=bitbucket-pipelines.yml . | tar -xv -C "${PACKAGE_PATH}"
      - cd "${PACKAGE_PATH}"
      - go get -v
      - env GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 go build
      - go build -v
      - cp fx_update.exe ${BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR}
    artifacts:
      - fx_update.exe
```

Comment: Amazing thank you! I tried multiple times with the full path, assuming something like this. Any idea why this didn't work either?

Comment: Not sure, but one common issue is that people try to use environment variables to define the artifacts paths, which doesn't works because the variables aren't evaluated.

Comment: As mentioned in the [documentation by atlassian](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/using-artifacts-in-steps-935389074.html), 
"_Files that are in the BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR at the end of a step can be configured as artifacts. The BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR is the directory in which the repository was initially cloned_"
Therefor it is necessary to have artifacts inside the initial cloned directory

Comment: @ShehanWeerasooriya It also says `Note: as these are glob patterns, path segments “.” And “..” won’t work. Use paths relative to the build directory.`  I believe I did this by giving the full path to the project `go/src/bitbucket.org/...` and so on. Maybe I mix something up though.